# ¿como cambiar los colores por defecto de los options de un select?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Lo que me gustaria realizar es que la lista desplegable que sale de un `select` que en este caso seria un conjunto de `options`, tenga un color de fondo diferente y cuando se pasen sobre ello modifique la tonalidad del mismo.

Codigo css:

```
    select option {
    color:Red;
    }
```

Ya aplique lo de arriba pero cargo la pagina y no me marca ningun cambio, la letra sigue siendo negra. El diseño si se puede aplicar en otras `clases` menos al tratar de hacer lo de los options.

Codigo General del Select (css):

```
select {

  /* styling */
  background-color: white;
  border: thin solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;

  /* reset */

  margin: 0;      
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, esto no es algo que se pueda hacer ahora mismo. En el estándar no se especifica nada y son los navegadores los que representan los options como quieran, por lo que incluso si encuentras una forma, seguramente no funcione en todos los navegadores. Para estilizarlo, quizás podrías usar un `ul`/`li` y simular un `select` con la lista

Comment: si es algo que acabo de ver, si pones tu respuesta argumentada la pondre como positiva

Comment: Pregunta: lo que quieres cambiar es la barra de color cuando se pasa el ratón por encima de una opción, no el color del texto en la misma, ¿correcto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguramente el problema es que **el color del texto en el `select`** (no el de los `option`) es el que sigue siendo negro.

### Solución:

Indicar el `color` para el `select`.

### Ejemplo:

```css
select,
option {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Opcion 1</option>
  <option>Opcion 2</option>
  <option>Opcion 3</option>
  <option>Opcion 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ya comprendo, pero hay una lista desplegable que aparece en negro, esa es la que quisiera modificar. no el option actualmente seleccionado sino el listado de opciones que aparecen

Comment: estoy usando mozilla firefox

Comment: ya lo probe en chrome, creo que es cuestion del navegador

Comment: @David, ya han [reportado este bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=910022) y ha sido marcado como solucionado. Se espera que en Firefox 52 este incluido el fix. Pero en Firefox 54 ya esta comprobado que fue solucionado.

Comment: si me actualizo al firefox mas reciente deberia de funcionar?

Comment: @David, yo tengo la ultima version y es la 51... verifica tu que version tienes.

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco, esto no es algo que se pueda hacer ahora mismo.

En el estándar no se especifica nada sobre los estilos de los `option` y son los navegadores los que los representan como quieran; por lo que incluso si encuentras una forma, seguramente no funcione en todos los navegadores.

Algunos respetan los atributos `color` y `background-color` pero no siempre es el caso: Chrome e IE sí lo hacen, Firefox no (aunque podría ser un bug como indica [Marcos Gallardo en un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48671/como-cambiar-los-colores-por-defecto-de-los-options-de-un-select?noredirect=1#comment85383_48673)), y sólo IE/Edge respetan los estilos del `:hover`. Así, el siguiente código se verá diferente en cada navegador:

```css
select { color:blue; }
option { color:red; background-color:yellow; }
option:hover { color:yellow; background-color:red; }
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Valor 1</option>
  <option>Valor 2</option>
  <option>Valor 3</option>
  <option>Valor 4</option>
</select>
```

Y la barra de color cuando se pasa el ratón por encima del `option` que yo sepa no se puede estilizar (en algunos casos ni siquiera existe, como en iOS donde las listas desplegables son "ruletas").

Para estilizar un `select`, quizás podrías usar un `ul`/`li` y simular la lista desplegable. Algunos frameworks como [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) tienen menús desplegables creados así y se puede cambiar su estilo fácilmente.